# Make a block element fill container vertically without manually fixing size

Tags: html, css, height

I have an outer element that is a fixed size with a footer immediately below it. Inside the element are two sections; the first should be a fixed height and the second should expand to fill the other element but not overflow it.

[Let me show you.](http://dabblet.com/gist/2722518)

How do I do this? setting `height: 100%` on the second element causes it to oveflow the outer element and overrun the footer. The only other alternative I see is to se the height explicitly in pixels which seems like it would be a mess.

What's the right way to do this?

***Edit:*** setting `overflow-y: hidden` will work in this very limited example, but its not actually limiting `section.inner2` and will look weird if for example I want to give `section.inner2` a border-radius

Comment: That is called a sticky footer. Google the term and try out the code.

Comment: @Blender thanks, I did not know the term. However I do not want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page, rather to the bottom of a fixed-size element.

Comment: That is no different. Replace `body` with a selector and it works exactly the same.

Comment: @Blender I'm sorry but that doesn't seem to be true. Here is the recommended setup: http://dabblet.com/gist/2722962 Notice the issue is that the grey section.s2 does not expand to fill its container on the veritcal axis. Here is my best attempt to replace body with a div.body: http://dabblet.com/gist/2722962 the same issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution that I can think of (and I don't think very much) is just using `position: absolute;`: http://jsfiddle.net/WLZmT/3/.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="fixed">
        Fixed.
    </div>
    <div id="fluid">
        Fluid.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#outer {
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(255, 200, 200);
    padding: 10px;

    height: 400px;
}

#fixed {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;

    background: rgb(200, 255, 200);
}

#fluid {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 255);

    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: ha, that's some crazy nonsense, but it might actually work for me.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>


    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
    }
    #container {
        left:50%;
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    #header {
        background:#ff0;
        padding:10px;
    }
    #body {
        padding:10px;
        padding-bottom:60px; /* Height footer */
    }
    #footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;            /* Height of the footer */
        background:#6cf;
    }


    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #container {
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        head
        <!-- Header end -->
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <!-- Body start -->

        <!-- Body end -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Footer start -->
footer
        <!-- Footer end -->
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, like the example I posted. Rather than sticking the footer to the bottom of the page, I want it to flow right after a fixed-sized container but I want elements within that container to fill it.

Comment: What do you mean? It's a simple matter. make an element expand vertically to the boundaries of its container but not beyond it. Please ask what is not clear from my example. I'll be glad to clear it up.

Comment: I am little confused because your example is identical to my answer. Where is the difference?

Comment: It is not. To be the same, #body would have to have a minimum height and two block elements with the second filling all the way to the bottom of body. Think of the use case where the body of the page has a minHeight (400px in my example) and is composed of a tab system. So the tab area is of fixed-ish size, but the rest of it should flow to the bottom of it's container.

Comment: I am sorry but this is too complicated for me to understand.